# Calculate and plot mean + confidence interval for multiple categories with poisson distribution in R

Tags: r, apply, categories, confidence-interval, poisson

I have a very hard time with making a plot of the mean + confidence interval for my dataset.
My dataset consists of 2 columns, to simplify:

```
df$category<- c("a", "d", "a", "q", "d", "d", "q", "d", "a", "q")
df$count<- c(3, 2, 0, 5, 0, 4, 8, 0, 2, 4)
```

So it has 3 category (a, d & q) which have corresponding count data. My real dataset follows a poisson distribution.

I want to calculate the mean of each category as well as the confidence interval and plot this in a bargraph.

As the categories have different lenghts, I made subsets of each category and tried the following:

```
        SE<- function(x) sd(x)/sqrt(length(x))
        lim1<-function(x) mean(x)-1.96*SE(x)
        lim2<-function(x) mean(x)+1.96*SE(x)

        confidence1a<-apply(a$count, lim1) 
        confidence2a<-apply(a$count, lim2)

        confidence1d<-apply(d$count, lim1) 
        confidence2d<-apply(d$count, lim2)
```

With the plan to binding them into one dataset afterwards

But this resulted in the errror:
Error in apply(a$count, FUN = lim1) : dim(X) must have a positive length

How can I fix this and not have to write out the formulas for each subset? My real dataset has 8+ categories... Also it would be nicer to not have to subset each category in the first place.

If anyone can make this into some nice code I would be forever grateful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some basic data manipulation with dplyr will allow easy plotting with ggplot here. Your calculation for the confidence interval of a Poisson distribution isn't quite right here - it shouldn't result in negative values, so I have changed it to the appropriate calculation:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  group_by(category) %>%
  summarize(mean = mean(count),
            upper = mean(count) + 1.96 * sqrt(mean(count)/n()),
            lower = mean(count) - 1.96 * sqrt(mean(count)/n())) %>%
  ggplot(aes(category, mean)) +
  geom_col(fill = 'deepskyblue4') +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = lower, ymax = upper), width = 0.5) +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 16)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! Almost there, but it is giving me the following error:
Error in `check_aesthetics()`:
! Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (3): x

when I check the length of my category, it is not the amount of categories (3) but the total of all rows (in the example, 10 in total). Any way to fix this?

Comment: An additional question, I want to extend this barplot by adding colours to the barplots based on a categorical variable consisting of 1 and 2. This is added as an additional column in the dataframe. It would make 2 columns of one colour and one column with another colour. When I do this with ```fill```` I get an error saying that aesthetics are not from the same length. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(
  category = c("a", "d", "a", "q", "d", "d", "q", "d", "a", "q"),
  count =  c(3, 2, 0, 5, 0, 4, 8, 0, 2, 4)
) %>%  
  arrange_all()

df %>%
  group_by(category) %>%  
  mutate(mean = mean(count), 
         conf_lower = mean - 1.96*(sd(count) * length(count)), 
         conf_upper = mean + 1.96*(sd(count) * length(count)))

# A tibble: 10 x 5
# Groups:   category [3]
   category count  mean conf_lower conf_upper
   <chr>    <dbl> <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>
 1 a            0  1.67      -7.32       10.6
 2 a            2  1.67      -7.32       10.6
 3 a            3  1.67      -7.32       10.6
 4 d            0  1.5      -13.5        16.5
 5 d            0  1.5      -13.5        16.5
 6 d            2  1.5      -13.5        16.5
 7 d            4  1.5      -13.5        16.5
 8 q            4  5.67      -6.57       17.9
 9 q            5  5.67      -6.57       17.9
10 q            8  5.67      -6.57       17.9
```